# Red-Black Tree fix sets all nodes to red

Tags: c, algorithm, red-black-tree

I've been tasked to implement an RB Tree recurrently, in ANSI C.

My support code all seems to be working fine, but when I test the code against a known result the pre-order traversal is incorrect, and all nodes are set red.

I suspect my `rbt_fix()` function is to blame - mostly because it's the only field were I'm playing with colour assignments without being completely sure about what I'm doing. I've checked my code against suggested psudo-code, and it looks correct.

Am I correct in handling my nodes after rotations? Am I supposed to set my root node pointer to the 'new root' with an extra assignment - I though that because the rotation code updates nodes and return the new root, manual re-assignment should be unnecessary?

Am I forgetting something fundamental about RBTs? I've checked my insertion code, and I'm certain they are calling rbt_fix at the appropriate time - immediately before returning.

The complete code is a bit lengthy to copy-paste here, but I've put copy as a gist on [on github](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/cfeb34b5776c72d26cb0d0636193e385), for the few of you who are willing to read the ugly code.

```
static rbt rbt_fix(rbt r) {
rbt R = r;
rbt A = R == NULL || R->left == NULL ? NULL : R->left;
rbt C = A == NULL || A->left == NULL ? NULL : A->left;
rbt D = A == NULL || A->right == NULL ? NULL : A->right;
rbt B = R == NULL || R->right == NULL ? NULL : R->right;
rbt E = B == NULL || B->left == NULL ? NULL : B->left;
rbt F = B == NULL ||B->right == NULL ? NULL : B->right;
if (IS_RED(A)) {
    if (IS_RED(C)) {
        if (IS_RED(B)) {
            R->colour = RED;
            A->colour = BLACK;
            B->colour = BLACK;
        } else if (IS_BLACK(B)) {
            R = rotate_right(R);
            A->colour = BLACK;
            R->colour = RED;
        }
    }
    if (IS_RED(D)) {
        if (IS_RED(B)) {
            R->colour = RED;
            A->colour = BLACK;
            B->colour = BLACK;
        } else if (IS_BLACK(B)) {
            A = rotate_left(A);
            R = rotate_right(R);
            D->colour = BLACK;
            R->colour = RED;
        }
    } 
}
if (IS_RED(B)) {
    if (IS_RED(E)) {
        if (IS_RED(A)) {
            R->colour = RED;
            A->colour = BLACK;
            B->colour = BLACK;
        } else if (IS_BLACK(A)) {
            B = rotate_right(B);
            R = rotate_left(R);
            E->colour = BLACK;
            R->colour = RED;
        }
    }
    if (IS_RED(F)) {
        if (IS_RED(A)) {
            R->colour = RED;
            A->colour = BLACK;
            B->colour = BLACK;
        } else if (IS_BLACK(F)) {
            R = rotate_left(R);
            B->colour = BLACK;
            R->colour = RED;
        }
    }
}
return R;
}
```

With the sequence of insertions `h,j,i,f,j,g,k,d,a,e,b,c`, I should be expecting the output:
 `g(black), d(red), b(b), a(r), c(r), f(b), e(r), i(r), h(b), k(b), j(r), i(r)`
 from a pre-order traversal, but my program currently outputs:

```
h, f, d, a, b, c, e, g, l, i, j, k (all red)
```

Thanks for the help.

[image: The nodes referenced in the code]

^ These are the nodes referenced in the code ^

Comment: It doesn't fix your problem (or it creates other problems), but your `IS_RED` macro has `BLACK == (x)->colour`, where you probably need `RED`. You also forgot to account for the null terminator when allocating memory for the string to copy.

Comment: Thank's a start, thanks, M Oehem. Now I'm getting some of the nodes colored black, not I'm losing a few notes somewhere in the fix. I'll see if I can find them by the memory leak the cause.

Comment: I guess _rbt.h_ is where `rbt` is defined?  Without having that, it is hard to know where to go with this.  In looking at the initialization statements: `rbt A = R == NULL || R->left == NULL ? NULL : R->left;` et. al., it is difficult also to know if order of operations is doing something unexpected.

Comment: Sorry, rbt is defined as follows: typedef struct rbt_node* rbt;

Comment: I added some brackets to the initialization with to avail. 
Currently I get h(r), g(b), c(r), j(b), k(r) using the preorder traversal with the (larger) input data set.

Comment: I can confirm that the cause of the bug is somewhere in the rbt_fix. When I comment out the call to rbt_fix() the code behave correctly for a binary search tree.

Comment: I would personally replace `R == NULL || R->left == NULL ? NULL : R->left;` with `R == NULL ? NULL : R->left;`, and so on.

Comment: Don't you need to recolour the nodes after rotating? Also, I think you are missing nodes, because the root can change and what was the root initially could be an interior node later on. Therefore, you should insert new items like this: `tree = rbt_insert(tree, "h");`. (In my opinion, passing a pointerto the root pointer would be safer and I'm not so fond of the ide of a dummy node, either.)